# php gettext don't work

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I'am trying to run gettext on a domain but there is an error anywhere...

on my local xampp installation works all fine but on the server are some bugs and I don't know how to debug gettext

this is my setup... the var is given in the url... e.g. es_ES

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) $lang = $_GET['lang'];
putenv("LC_ALL=$lang");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain("messages");
```

and this is the path to my translation files
    /httpdocs/locale/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES

Has anybody an idea?

Kind regards,

Bob

Comment: do i have to compile some files on the server again?

Comment: please include the errors you're getting in the question

Comment: the thing is that there are no errors displayed

Comment: "on the server are some bugs", what does this mean?

Comment: sry for the incorrect formulation... there are no errors displayed... just the default language is shown

Comment: don't know how to run this

Comment: first things you should check is that is gettext installed on the server (does it show up on phpinfo) and are [locales installed on the server](http://www.codekites.com/php-get-list-of-locales-installed-on-system/).

Comment: gettext is installed now i am trying to get this localss list

Comment: via ssh shows only C & POSIX after entering "locale -a"...

Comment: so i've installed some more languages... but everytime says "dpkg-trigger: dpkg-trigger must be called from a maintainer script (or with a --by-package option)
"

Comment: everytime says... what says? I've already asked you to add any relevant error messages to the actual question.

Comment: ok, remember to accept the answer too if that was the case (when you can)

Answer (score 1):

> via ssh shows only C & POSIX after entering "locale -a".

You don't have locales installed on the server then. Your system will *only* support the locales installed on your OS, in the *exact* format given by your OS like explained in [manual comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#91187).

Someone has to install the locales there. If you're not the admin, the server admin needs to do it.